# How to avoid that splash screen launch again while pressing back button from home screen in android

Tags: android

while pressing back button from home screen then application goes to background and when lifting the app from background, app start from splash screen. but I want to start the app from home screen.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  static  final long SPLASH_DURATION = 3000L;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        mHandler =  new Handler();
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dismissSplash();
            }
        };

        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismissSplash();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, SPLASH_DURATION);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }

    private void dismissSplash(){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `finish()` in splash activity while call intent.

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(ScreenSplash.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();`

Comment: yes I am using finish().

Comment: then show us your code, if you are using finish()

Comment: Check this https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `finish()` method before you call your home activity.

```
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yourActivity.class));
```

if it doesn't work, handle `onBackPressed` in your home activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true); //it goes to background.
}
```

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Cagri. Second option is working

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Please Add flag as given below when start activity from splash

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity);     
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);     
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);   
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);     
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

please use `SplashActivity.this` instead of `this` because you are calling dismissSplash from another thread.

```
   private void dismissSplash()
   {
      startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
      SplashActivity.this.finish();
   }
```

Comment: it's not working